# Problem about a simple division

Tags: arithmetic

My little sister wants me to divide $135628$ by $339$. I can not make her understand that quotient is $400$ and remainder is $28$. She does not understand how one last $0$ comes after $40$. She knows the relation among divisor ,dividend,quotient and remainder. So she can understand it by applying backward method ,that is by taking  quotient ($400$) and then put other respective values to get back the dividend. But She can not realize it in a straight forward way. And so I am here to get some valuable advice about how I can make *the division* crystal clear to her. With regards...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\color{green}{1356}:339 &= \mathbf 4&\text{ remainder }&\color{red}0\\
{\color{red}0}\color{green}2:339 &= \mathbf 0&\text{ remainder }&{\color{red}2}\\
{\color{red}2}\color{green}8:339 &= \mathbf 0&\text{ remainder }&\mathbf {28}\\
\therefore \color{green}{135602}:339& = \mathbf{400}&\text{ remainder }&\mathbf{28}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for the lucid explanation.